# Testing SLIM appication against API Specification with PHPUnit

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, swagger, openapi

I have an API, written in PHP with `Slim` (3, will be upgraded to 4 soon), I also have an extensive specification written in `openapi3` YML format (I could convert to another format if necessary, but I think it would be the best to keep oas3). Currently I am testing all endpoint against this specification with [Dredd](https://dredd.org). This is a Tool which goes through a API specification an, sends example data to the real API and checks if the result matches the spec. That works, but not very good. For a test run I have to wipe out and re-initialize the db with PHP and then run Dredd with npm. Plus since Dredd does not support all features of oas3 I have to do some conversion first.

Since I have some Unit-tests with PHPUnit anyway, I would love to run the other tests with PHPUnit as well (and get rid of the Node-stuff at all). I found http://opensource.byjg.com/php-swagger-test/ and https://github.com/Maks3w/SwaggerAssertions. Both of them provide this very feature, but I would have to write a separate function for every endpoint, containing sample data and so on - stuff which is already in the API spec. Any Idea how I could avoid this afford and just use my API spec as test defintion with PHPUnit or at least any PHP library?

Example from the specs:

```yaml
  /users:
    get:
      summary: get a list of users
      description: get info about all registered users - in whole application or in a workspace.

      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: AuthToken
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/auth'
          example:
            at: 132token
        - in: query
          name: ws
          description: id of a workspace to get users from. can be omitted for all users in system
          required: false
          examples:
            a:
              value: 0
            b:
              value: 1
```

With byjg php-swagger-test I would have to write something like this

```php
    public function usersA()
    {
        $request = new \ByJG\Swagger\SwaggerRequester();
        $request
            ->withMethod('GET')
            ->withPath("/users")
            ->withHEader(blabla)
            ->withRequestBody(['ws'=>0]);

        $this->assertRequest($request);
    }
    public function usersB()
    {
        $request = new \ByJG\Swagger\SwaggerRequester();
        $request
            ->withMethod('GET')
            ->withPath("/users")
            ->withHEader(blabla)
            ->withRequestBody(['ws'=>1]);

        $this->assertRequest($request);
    }
```

Two tests (functions) containing only information which is already in the spec. Is there a better tool/way to run tests over all endpoints against the spec without writing all those?

Comment: cant you just load in the definitions and parse to an array, and basically build each request depending what's there?

Comment: Yes I could. But this not a very trivial or easy task, because oas3 allows a lot of stuff, so I hoped to find some framework which already did it.

Comment: Unit testing and integration testing don't mix, they work on totally different levels. Unit testing works from inside of the app and thus implies a certain level of "white box" knowledge about the SUT, while API testing is an outside thing and sees the SUT as a black box stranger. Both are totally different approaches to testing. Trying to look from inside and see self as a black box is somewhat schizophrenic behavior.

Comment: The main objective of the unit test in this case is guarantee the specification you create still correct. If the tests discover and ran automatically against the specification, a change in your OAS3 could pass, however you did not expected that change. I know this is "kind of" a toil work but it will save a lot of work when you want to find exactly what was changed.